# After Upgrade to 12.04 the Login takes forever

Tags: 12.04, login, xubuntu, authentication, pam

I recently upgraded from Xubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. Since then it takes a very long time for me to Login.

The time it takes to get to the login screen is normal but after I type in my password it takes over a minute to get me to my desktop. In 11.10 this only took a couple of seconds.

How to solve this?

Comment: There may be a issue with the your PAM configuration, consider editing your question to include the PAM and authentication tags

Comment: This is a problem for me too. Did you ever find out of it? I see there's many services timing out, so I guess all of those timeouts in the end is what makes stuff slow. Only slow for graphical, not for console.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand you right: You will finally succeed with logging in, right?

Then we must clarify if this happens with both: **graphical login** and **console login**. For console login you will have to press: Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login via that console. (Don't forget to logout afterwards)

If also the console login takes this long time to login, then there could be something wrong with your PAM configuration, NFS shares,... it will pretty hard to say whats wrong without any additional information on your setup.

Have you tried to create a new user? Does login then succeed within reasonable time? When yes you could try to delete or move your configuration files like .gconf etc. and then try again.

Please also check your /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth for errors within the time of login.